# Unable to boot Lubuntu 20.04 after a clean install

Tags: grub2, 20.04, lubuntu, bios, grub-legacy

I had a old nettop on which I thought I would install Lubuntu. I installed Lubuntu and the installation was successful. But when I restarted after the installation the system wont boot. it will say `no Bootable disk found`. I also tried to repair the boot with boot-repair. Still no luck.
Below is the pastebin info from Boot-repair

```
boot-repair-4ppa125                                              [20200901_0535]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================




Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub2 of
sda1 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s



Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/etc/default/grub

========================= Reinstall the grub2 of sda1 ==========================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.2

==> Reinstall the GRUB of sda1 into the MBR of sda

grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /media/lubuntu/58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[73155]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 14999: /bin/sh

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32800 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on sda1

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
EFI in dmesg.
[   71.188831] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Store a System Token in an EFI Variable being skipped.



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x975662f8
      Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1        2048 976768064 976766017 465.8G 83 Linux
Disk sdb: 14.62 GiB, 15682240512 bytes, 30629376 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0217ce81
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 30629375 30627328 14.6G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk zram0: 247.2 MiB, 259198976 bytes, 63281 sectors
Disk zram1: 247.2 MiB, 259198976 bytes, 63281 sectors
Disk zram2: 247.2 MiB, 259198976 bytes, 63281 sectors
Disk zram3: 247.2 MiB, 259198976 bytes, 63281 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:ATA ST3500418AS:;
1:1049kB:500GB:500GB:ext4::;
sdb:15.7GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:SanDisk Cruzer Blade:;
1:1049kB:15.7GB:15.7GB:fat32::boot, lba;
zram3:259MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:259MB:259MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram1:259MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:259MB:259MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram2:259MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:259MB:259MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
zram0:259MB:unknown:4096:4096:loop:Unknown:;
1:0.00B:259MB:259MB:linux-swap(v1)::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL   PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                               
└─sda1 ext4     58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa 975662f8-01                                  
sdb                                                                                               
└─sdb1 vfat     A6BD-F480                            0217ce81-01                          LUBUNTU 
zram0                                                                                             
zram1                                                                                             
zram2                                                                                             
zram3                                                                                                

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

       Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1   429.4G   1% /media/lubuntu/58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa
sdb1    12.9G  11% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
sdb1   ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic   58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=58a4b883-7c41-491c-bca4-0e2d885513aa /              ext4    defaults   0 1

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.000980377 = 0.001052672    boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 130.139995575 = 139.736756224  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   1.379024506 = 1.480716288    boot/vmlinuz                                   2
   1.379024506 = 1.480716288    boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic                  2
   1.379024506 = 1.480716288    boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
   1.457019806 = 1.564463104    boot/initrd.img                                3
   1.457019806 = 1.564463104    boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic               3
   1.457019806 = 1.564463104    boot/initrd.img.old                            3

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Jul 31 00:34 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Jul 31 00:34 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jul 31 00:34 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jul 31 00:34 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jul 31 00:34 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jul 31 00:34 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jul 31 00:34 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Start Lubuntu
Start Lubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[73155]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 3014: /bin/bash
```

What am I doing wrong ? How should I fix this issue?

Comment: I am seeing a mix of i386 and 20.04. 20.04 is 64 bit only, there is no 32 bit. Is your CPU 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: you could run the advanced options in boot-repair by following this tutorial. However, the comment by KGIII must be taken into consideration.
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/

Comment: My Motherboard is non efi legacy BIOS mother board. the processor is 64 bit Intel atom 1.6 ghz dual core processor. Seems the grub installed is not getting detected. when I tried using a third party utility to boot like Super GRUB2 Disk i was able to login to the installed version. So I think it is something to do with BIOS, EFI , grub2 etc. and hope there are others who are facing the same issue